# $\log_2(8)= a$; $\log_2(5)= b$; $\log_2(7) = c$; express $\log_2\sqrt{21}$ in terms of $a, b, c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, solution-verification

Not sure where to start with this question.

I could try

\begin{align}
& \frac12\log_2(21) \\[6pt]
& \frac12\log_2(7 \cdot 3) \\[6pt]
& \frac12\log_2(7) + \frac12\log_2(3) \\[6pt]
& \frac12(c) + 1/2\log_2(5 \cdot 3/5) \\[6pt]
& \frac12(c) + \frac12\log_2(5) + \log_2(3/5) \\[6pt]
& \frac12(c) + \frac12(b) + \log_2(\frac{3}{40}\cdot{8}) \\[6pt]
& \frac12(c) + \frac12(b) + \log_2(8) + \log_2(\frac{3}{40}) \\[6pt]
& \frac12(c) + \frac12(b) + (a) + \log_2(\frac{3}{40}) \\[6pt]
\end{align}

If this is on the right track please let me know. If not then if you could give me a hint in the right direction that would be great thank you.

Comment: You've written that $a=3$.  Are you sure you have inputted the expression correctly?  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your expressions.

Comment: The most likely possibility is that there is a typo in the problem statement. Something that has $3$ as a factor is bound to appear there. Could it be, for example, $\log_3(8)=a$ rather than $\log_2(8)=a$?

Comment: I believe it is the correct problem statement. I tried to manipulate the log into terms of a b c

Comment: How about $\log_2 3+c$? Probably not what you are looking for, but the problem statement does not exclude it.

Comment: @StinkingBishop The $3$ was there, see below.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Indeed, I can see how this would count as a correct solution. If that is what they meant in the problem setup, then it leaves a bit of a bitter taste in the mouth. If the solution is allowed to contain constants (like $2$) and logarithms, then why not add an additional constant ($21$) and say the solution is just $\frac{1}{2}\log_2(21)$... Maybe also $3=2^a-2^b$???

Comment: stinking bishop has a valid point.  Why wouldn't $\log_2{\sqrt{7a}}$ be acceptable answer.  It *is* in terms of $a,b,c$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes the question is very vaguely expressed, but I like that we've had some chance to be creative!

Answer (score 3):

$a=\log_2(8) =3$ since $2^3 = 8$,  so that is the point where the $3$ comes in.

So, $\log_2(\sqrt 21) = \frac 12\log_2(21) = \frac 12(\log_2 3 + \log_2 7) = \frac{1}{2}(\log_2 a + c)$ should be acceptable. (No $b$ is used)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the "intended" solution is this:

$\log_2(\sqrt{21})=\frac{1}{2}\log_2(3\cdot 7)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log_2(3)+ \log_2(7)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log_2(8-5)+c\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log_2(2^a-2^b)+c\right)$

Comment: Or $21=25-4=5^2-8^{2/3}$ so $\log_2\sqrt{21}=\frac{1}{2}\log_2(2^{2b}-2^{2/3a})$??? Really the problem would be a lot cleaner if you could get $21$ from $8, 5, 7$ using only multiplication and exponentiation - the way it is given, I am still not 100% sure it's not a typo.

Comment: +1 for you, that was a good one.